# sqlite insert with default values for default fields

Tags: sql, sqlite

The docs specify two alternatives: `insert values` or `insert default values` 
(https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

The trouble is if one for example has a table:

```
create table address_book values(
 rowid integer primary key, 
 first_name, 
 last_name, 
 address, 
 phone_number, 
 email, notes, 
 country TEXT DEFAULT 'USA'
 )
```

One can no longer write `insert into values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` since it expects `rowid` and `country` to be specified. Is there a shortcut for specifying `insert into values` with default values populating the default fields? Or is impossible without explicitly naming all the non-default fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is impossible.  In any event it is good practice to explicitly name the columns you are `INSERT`ing into anyway -- leaving the columns out leads to more fragile code and more "silent failure" possibilities in which you're not inserting data into the column you think you are inserting it into.